# How to upgrade Apache on a Windows server?

Tags: apache, apache2, webserver

I have just upgraded our webserver from PHP 5.3.6 to 5.3.10, and I now want to upgrade Apache as well from 2.2.17 to 2.2.22 (on a **Windows Server**). How do I go about this in a good way (on a live webserver)? A little downtime is alright, but not too much.

Apache is installed via an MSI installer and I'm not sure how to upgrade safely with the least downtime.
Do I just download the latest installer and install that? And what about my config files? I don't think it's possible to have both instances installed 'next to each other'? Or is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For anyone else who searches for this, I found that uninstalling the old Apache (in my case, 2.2.22) from Add/Remove Programs and installing the new version (in my case, 2.2.24) kept all the previous settings.

We had locked down the httpd.conf file and had an application that modified/added files in the "htdocs" directory.

Upon uninstalling and re-installing, all of these files were left unchanged and the new version of Apache Server is reflected.

Comment: How long did it take yo to perform these actions?

Answer (score 1):

I did it today on windows server 2012R2, apache was installed from "source" (installer was not used-updated to 2.4.55):

1.Stop apache service

2.Rename apache directory (from `C:\Apache24` to `C:\Apache24-old`)

3.Extract `Apache24` folder from zip archive downloaded from apache web site to original location (`C:\`)

4.Copy conf folder from previous installation to the extracted folder (Copy `C:\Apache24-old\conf` to `C:\Apache24\conf`-overwrite)

5.(Optional), if you have any certs copy it from `C:\Apache24-old\` to `C:\Apache24`

6.Start apache service,no issues faced

Comment: One more way to do it, if step 2 is not working (the renaming), is to: extract your Apache24 download to Apache24-new; delete the `conf` folder in Apache24-new;  stop Apache; copy Apache24 over to Apache24-old (for backup); copy Apache24-new onto Apache24, and finally restart Apache. I had to go from 2.4.39 to 2.4.57

Answer (score 0):

- Download a latest version of apache installer.
- Make the necessary config changes.
- Run it on a different port, other than your live server.
- If things work well, correct the port number, and replace.

It will really take a little down-time.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried to install a newer version, but running into this error: "Another version of this product is already installed. Installation of this version cannot continue. To configure or remove the existing version of this product, use Add/Remove Programs."...

Comment: hmm, now I think you should go with using a self-extractable version of Apache. and follow the above steps. install its services, so that it should start everytime your windows starts.